# Changing interval of a data with highcharts

Tags: php, charts, highcharts

I am using the great highchart for my data processing. so i need to change the x axis with this kind of date format : 17-MAR-2010 and each point in the x-axis is one week. that means the next point is 24-MAR-2010. So my script for the chart is this,

```
$('#chart1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: "Graphical Analysis for <?php echo $projectName; ?>"
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: "From Date Range : <?php echo $startDateProject .' ~ '. $endDateProject ?>"
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: true,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year. i need to change this to 27-MAR-2010 eg
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (Kg)'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 2000000000,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'PROJECTED WEIGHT',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
        }, {
            name: 'ACHIEVED WEIGHT',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
        }]
    });
```

Please help me with this. every increment is one week.

Comment: And you wish to use categories for the x-axis?

Comment: Have you tried to set `pointInterval: 7 * 2400 * 3600 * 1000` ? Just like pointStart.

Comment: Od course there should be `7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000`.